# How to move n amount of spaces in a 2d board game scala

Tags: scala

```
def ar() {
    playerX = playerX + 1
    checkBounty();
    if(field(playerX)(playerY) == true) {
      getPlayerPos();
```

That's the code to move a player one space to the right, but what would be the code if I wanted to move the player n amount of spaces to the right?

Comment: Some example input and output would help make this more clear. Perhaps adding a parameter `n` to the function `ar()` and then doing `playerX + n` would help.

Comment: def ar(n: Int) {
    playerX + n
  }
you mean like that?

Comment: Ya, something like that. Without seeing your data structure which I believe is `field` can't say for sure.

Comment: private var field: Array[Array[Boolean]] = Array.ofDim[Boolean](10, 10) - this is for the field,

private var bounties: Array[Array[Int=>Int]] = Array.ofDim[Int=>Int](10, 10) - this is for the bounties,

would a for loop be useful?
and I don't understand playerX + n, could you please explain more?

Comment: `n` is the number of spaces to move. `n` could be `1`,`2`, or any number passed in as a parameter. I would suggest to try and solve a simpler problem using a one-deimensional board to help understand how this might work.